# Google Chrome frequently and randomly crashing?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, 19.04

Has anyone else had trouble with Chrome crashing randomly and frequently? Just now I was looking at the screen reading something and it just crashed. It didn't freeze or anything, just disappeared. I haven't noticed anything making it any more or less stable. I looked around the interwebs and wasn't able to see anyone else having this problem.

Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Ubuntu 19.04

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean chromium-browser (or Chrome)?  How come you're on 75.0?  For chromium-browser, even Ubuntu 19.10 is only up [74.0.3729.169-0ubuntu2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&keywords=chromium) .  Chromium has never crashed on me (knock on wood...).  But perhaps you can try deleting any settings and uninstalling any add-ons?

Comment: Hello! No I just have Chrome not Chromium, when I downloaded Ubuntu I went to chrome.google.com and it had a deb installer for Linux. Anytime it has an update, I update it. I copy/pasted the text from within the browser settings.

Comment: If you go to the Chrome website and hit download, it has a popup that says, `Download Chrome for Linux
Debian/Ubuntu/Fedora/openSUSE.

Please select your download package:

 64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)
 64 bit .rpm (For Fedora/openSUSE)`

Comment: Why don't you try chromium?  Install the package `chromium-browser`.  It is an open-source version of Chrome.  Having said that, I think you might want to remove any settings and add-ons, like I suggested and start from there.  Then add add-ons back one-by-one.

Comment: I will try that, thank you! I thought Chrome would be more stable than Chromium but it's not like I have anything to lose, haha. I noticed today a new program my work uses (ZenDesk Chat) causes it to crash a lot more than normal.

Comment: Again, I actually think the problem is not with the browsers but the ***settings*** associated with your browser and/or the add-ons you've installed.  Whether you use Chrome, Chromium, or Firefox, I think it's safe to say that many people have used any one of these.  But you might be the only one who is using one of these with a particular combination add-ons that's causing it to crash.  As for installing the current version for your version of Ubuntu instead of the latest version, the main advantage is that most people on Ubuntu 19.10 would be using the same version and can help you better.

Comment: @Ray I began running Chromium and Chrome, Chromium for work and Chrome for personal. I've tried running it with no extensions and without logging into my Google accounts, but it still happens. And I thought 19.10 wasn't out until Fall of 2019, are some people granted earlier access or something?

Comment: Sorry!!!  My mistake -- I meant 19.04 .  Though, as far as I know, once 19.04 came out, 19.10 is "available", in the sense a version is given to it and you could upgrade to it.  For example, [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/chromium-browser) is Chromium for 19.10.  I don't recommend going to it, though, as you should sort out your problem with 19.04 first.

Comment: As for your problem, by settings with your browser, I didn't mean connecting to your Google accounts.  There are some settings that are stored in your home directory.  You would have to delete them -- a easier solution is to create a '''new''' user account and try running Chromium.  If there is a difference between them, then it's something in your account (i.e., the settings I meant) that is the cause.  If there is no difference, then we're a step closer to believing that maybe it's a problem with Chromium.  Also, do try the Chromium package that's installed with 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the base project is **Chromium**, Google use this as the base, for the Google Chrome browser, so if the bug is in **Chromium**, it is likely in **Google Chrome** as well.

Google released a new version **75.0.3770.100**, it feels a little better, but still suffers the same problems, can't say I looked at the release notes to see if they had fixed it, not even sure I'd be able to identify the issue anyway. This has basically meant I have not been able to use either browser in the last few weeks, luckily I can use Firefox and therefore have been, but for work, testing in Chromium or Chrome has been a nightmare.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I think it could be caused by the extensions so I've gone down to the bare minimum. I use Chromium for personal and Chrome for work, and I can't tell a difference between the two as far as stability is concerned. Oh well, it's a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running eset anti-virus software and have found that if I kill all eset processes then Chrome stops crashing. In other threads I've seen mention of simply disabling 'real time file protection' but that did not work for me. I've no idea if the problem is in Eset or Chrome (or Chromium, which also has the same problem) and I've found the problem in versions of chrome since 79.0.3945.88-1 and the previous version plus later versions 80.0.3987.16-1 and 81.0.4000.3-1.

Interestingly one of the symptoms is that you see the webpage flash several times as you move about the webpage and after a few minutes Chrome or Chromium crashes. Looking at the console output each flash corresponds with a crash being reported then sometimes prior to the crash an invalid opcode.

As to whether it's a bug in eset or chrome I've no idea at present.

I'm running KDE Neon (Ubuntu 18.04LTS). The problem for me started at the beginning of December 2019 after an update.

Answer (score -2):

It's a problem with **Chromium** itself, I have both Chromium and Google Chrome on Debian (sid). Both my versions are `75.0.3770.80`. Both browsers are constantly crashing on me, seconds after browser is opened, so at the moment I can only use Firefox, or downgrade to the previous version.

Please don't say things like just use **Chromium** it's not a good answer. By all means reference it as the person might not be aware of it; but, it doesn't answer the question and it may even be that they don't have a choice.

Comment: "just use Chromium" [in order to solve their problem], wasn't exactly what I said...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I currently am running both but I haven't noticed a difference in stability between the two. And I just can't with Firefox so I don't use it, haha.